# How does xyz.js.erb work in Rails?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I know for an action in a controller we can have code like this

```
def xyz
    @user=User.find params[:id]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html 
        format.xml { ... }
        format.json { ... }
        format.js {...}
    end
end
```

So they will respond with xyz.html.erb, xyz.xml.erb, xyz.json.erb and xyz.js.erb. For the first three I think they are going to respond with html, xml and json format data. What I don't understand is how javascript type data will be pass to the browser. Why I care about this is I may want to write some logical operations that don't want browser or the reader to know but normal javascript will show every detail to the browser so that the browser know how to process the items in the page.

Given xyz.js.erb has the following code

```
$("#the_box").append("<%= @user.age*1.5 %>");
```

what will the browser get as the response? I don't want the browser to know the logical part `@user.age*1.5`.

Comment: I think someone better read will be able to provide a more specific answer, but you may wish to look at [ExecJS](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs). I don't know much more than that, except the JS file will "run", allowing you to change your DOM as a result

Comment: Why don't you test it out?  Just start server, send request & look at file.

Comment: I tested it and I didn't find a javascript file with chrome web dev tool on the browser side. In the server side it just sais `Rendered xyz.js.erb` but didn't specify how this will be shown to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Much as with an html.erb file, the contents of the erb tags `<%= ... %>` is evaluated server side and the browser only sees the result of that, ie something like

```
$("#the_box").append("42");
```

What happens next depends on how this file was requested. For example if you used jquery with dataType set to `script` (or if you don't set it but jquery infers it) then jquery will evaluate that javascript for you. If you had made the request by inserting a script tag then the browser would execute it directly.